# How to handle what seems to be an attack on your account rep?

Tags: discussion

I went to a meeting for an hour to come back and find I'd lost 62 rep... Being somewhat surprised, I had a look:

[image]

It really looks like someone is going round finding all my answers and marking them down - I'm not going to pretend all these are perfect and so on, but it just seems very odd that in the space of an hour - so much all came in at the same time.

Comment: Pretty sure there's a duplicate question for this, basically a script runs daily (I think) that looks for behaviour like this and will correct it

Comment: Yes, @George, there is a script. It runs at 3.00 AM, UTC. If the downvotes are still there tomorrow, BugFinder, then you can contact SO using the "Contact Us" form.

Comment: Sigh - even my search fu is having a bad day :( perhaps hibernation should be a thing

Comment: @BugFinder Well, if it makes you feel a little better - many of us have been the target of serial downvoting. Welcome to the club! And rest assured that by tomorrow, the downvoter will have gotten some, urm, friendly information from the moderator team >:->

Comment: :D Ive had some questionable down votes in the past but not this many .. may they find their crotch infested with flees and their arms too short to scratch

Comment: It is pretty visible who did this.  If question really sucks then not commenting is always best.  Luckily he only stopped when his index finger gave out, no problems getting this cancelled again.

Comment: @HansPassant I must be stupid - I dont know how to see who downvoted something

Comment: That is intentional, they don't want you to take counter-measures by yourself.  A good strategy is to only post a comment when the question shows some hope of being useful when it is worked on by the OP.  If it is all a lost cause then just DV and move on.

Comment: @HansPassant true, but you speak as if it is obvious to you who did - I havent the time or inclination to get them back for it there is other stuff to be doing. I was more curious that it felt like I was missing something obvious

Comment: Looking through your comment history it must be Jon Skeet ... wait ...